# How to get element (DOM) of dynamic attribute ,if it's inside <ng-template > angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body"
                           let-node="rowData">
                <button type="button"
                        [disabled]="hasValid(node)"
                        *ngIf="getBtnLabel(node)"
                        class="btn btn-default btn-sm"
                        [attr.data-v]="rAddBtn(node)"
                        translate>
                  <i class="s s-plus"
                     aria-hidden="true"></i> {{getBtnLabel(node)}}
                </button>
</ng-template>
```

but i'm not able to get the attribute "data-v" through directive i have made. code is working fine if it's inside the "div" block instead of ng-template.
Below is my directive that i have made

```
import {
  Directive,
  ElementRef,
  OnInit,
} from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
  // tslint:disable-next-line
  selector: '[data-v]'
})
export class DataVandvDirective implements OnInit {
  vAttribute: string;
  constructor(private element: ElementRef) {
    const native = this.element.nativeElement;
    this.vAttribute = native.getAttribute('data-v');
    console.log("the v att", this.vAttribute);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to put your code into ngAfterViewInit() function. The Element may not be rendered at time the constructor is called.

```ts
export class DataVandvDirective implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
vAttribute: string;
constructor(private element: ElementRef) { }

ngOnInit(): void { }
}

ngAfterViewInit(): void {

    const native = this.element.nativeElement;
    this.vAttribute = native.getAttribute('data-v');
    console.log("the v att", this.vAttribute);
}
```